# h2 database bit wise operation(&) invalid syntax MySql

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation, h2, bitwise-operators

Bit wise operations (`&,&&,|,||`) for h2 database error creates invalid syntax error.

```
Connection con=jdbcCon.getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status & 128");
//this version works -> BITAND(`status`,128) ");
```

I tried jdbc connection with `;MODE=MySQL` and without it. SQL query is correct in MySQL database. 
BITAND operator works, still I guess bit operator should be supported.

```
Exception:
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error SQL statement: SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status & 128 [50000-181]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.CoordinateSequenceFilter
```

POM:
        
            com.h2database
            h2
            1.4.181
            test

Comment: There is no boolean operator `&` or `||` in SQL. In fact `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL. The boolean operators are `and` and `or`. You are talking about bitwise operators. I changed the subject accordingly

Comment: adding to pom http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.13 produce 
Syntax error in SQL statement, still bitwise operations not work as expected. I also found https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/h2-database/bitwise/h2-database/ZNw3MREjG_c/wfnGZD_dKZEJ so it might still not be implemented.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/h2database/issues/detail?id=552
This issue seems to be related, still no solution proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The && operator in H2 is reserved for bounding box intersections test. This is why H2 try to load JTS Topology Suite library.

For bitwise operations, you have to use the following H2 functions:

- http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#bitand
- http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#bitor
- http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#bitxor

Comment: So MySQL mode will not change(understand) that query, so it is not fully mysql compatible? Does it mean all production query has to be rewritten to be compatible?

Comment: The parser of H2 need to be modified in order to manage | & ^ operators. You can see here one of the part of the parser on operator feature https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/command/Parser.java#3671 . You should post on H2 google group in order to add this feature request.